# Could not load file or assembly when starting complex ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, dll, asp.net-core

I have complex ASP.NET Core solution, which consists of:

- Web part, which is ASP.NET Core Web Api project
- other parts, which are .NET Core class libraries

I want to add extension method to this class libraries, so they could register themselves, e.g.:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddThisLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    //a lot of addTransient...
    return services;
}
```

which I use in `Startup` class in `ConfigureServices` method, like this:

```
services.AddThisLibrary();
```

The problem is, that when I'm starting my application, it throws the exception:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyProject.API.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   MyProject.API.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)

for each my library.

I've checked */bin/Debug* folder, where I have all my class libraries built in **DLL**, so I have no idea, why they can't be found.

How can I properly write such extension methods and remove that exception?

Answer (score 0):

you should check that your dll is the same version as the one it is trying to load it, what i suggest is go to your reference, remove the existing one, go to your assembly remove it as well, then clean, then add it to your references again, build. 
Make sure you have one reference only.

Comment: I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, checking again and again. What do you mean by one reference?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx) will help

Answer (score 0):

My case may be specific a lot, but I faced this error when changed target from .net core 3.1 to .net 5. Some files in deploy folder remained from prevous deploys. I clean the folder an published once again.